# Qual diferença entre Prototype e um Object?

Tags: javascript

Utilizo new para criar objetos no javascript e pelo que reparei de forma bem superficial não há uma grande diferença entre a instancia com new e utilizar o prototype.

Qual a diferença e qual vantagem em usar o prototype?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Object em JavaScript herdam as propriedades e os métodos do seu Prototype.

Isso é o Prototype:

```
function Pessoa(nome, idade) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.idade = idade;
}
```

Isso é o Object:

```
var objeto = new Person("Hudson", "26");
console.log(objeto.nome);
```

Vantagem é a mesma que no Object Oriented, voce pode ler esse artigo [aqui](http://dev.rbtech.info/vantagens-de-programar-com-orientacao-a-objetos-oop/)